# tinyMCE change event is working but not hidden textarea's

Tags: tinymce, textarea

I have initiated the tinyMCE for the list of textarea's (around 12) using the below code (generated from TypeScript code).

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: this.selector,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change blur', function () {
                editor.save();
                tinymce.triggerSave();
                console.info('tinyMCE change event fired.');
            });
        },
        branding: this.branding,
        menubar: this.menubarFlag,
        browser_spellcheck: this.browser_spellcheck,
        fontsize_formats: this.fontsize_formats,
        block_formats: this.block_formats,
        toolbar1: this.toolbar1,
        height: this.height,
        plugins: this.plugins
    });
```

I tried both editor.save(); and tinymce.triggerSave(); on tinyMCE change event. But still hidden textarea change event is not firing though content is updated to textarea.

I need textarea's event to actually add an element to the form by adding name attribute.

```
    $(divObj).find('.segment-input').change(function () {
         $(divObj).find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name', $(divObj).find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name-nochange'));
         $(divObj).find('input[type="hidden"]').removeAttr('name-nochange');
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete, verifiable example that shows what you have built?  That will help people understand what code is running and when.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @michael-fromi, question updated. I am using text area change event to actually add an element to the form by renaming name-nochange attribute to name attribute. This can not be done on tinyMCE change event as it initialized for around 12 textarea's.

Comment: When you make changes in TinyMCE you are not interacting with the underlying `textarea` so you won't trigger any of its native events.  You could try to programmatically do that when the editor's events are triggered.  Is there any reason you can't use the editor event to interact with the DOM of the page?

Comment: @michael-fromi, as I mentioned earlier, tinyMCE initialized for almost 12 instance on the same page. Is it possible to access particular textarea on which user is currently working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments above check out this fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Cogaab

The `editor.on()` function has access to the editor (`e` in the fiddle) upon which it was triggered.  You can get (among other things) the target ID of the underlying text area.  In the fiddle I provided I log that to the console for each of the editors on `init`, `change`, and `blur`.

Once you know the ID you can find that using JavaScript and do what you need to that native element.

There is a variety of useful data in that editor (`e`) object - its worth logging `e` and looking at what else is there as other data there may also be helpful for your scenario.